# TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am doing this piece of code:

```
 var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

    // Connect to the db
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://${server}:27017/${db}", function(err, db) {
      if(!err) {
        console.log("successfully connected to the database");
      }else{
        console.log("Error on connecting... aborting and exiting");
        return console.dir(err);
        throw err;
       }
        db.authenticate('username', 'password', function(err, res) {
        var startId = 7882;
        var userCount = 100;
        var num = 190;
        var baseGeologOrig = db.geologs.find({user_id:279, created_at:{$gte:new ISODate("2015-01-31"), $lte:new ISODate("2015-02-02")}}).limit(1227);
        var baseGeolog = [];
      // callback
        console.log("Reached here...!");


       });
    });
```

after I am connected to the database and tried to do some operations I got the following error:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:97
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at /home/Scripts/MongoScript.js:16:36
    at handleCallback (/usr/lib/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:95:12)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1320:22
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:565:28
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:1013:20
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/mongocr.js:118:17
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:754:46
    at Callbacks.emit (/usr/lib/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:95:3)
    at null.messageHandler (/usr/lib/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:243:23)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:262:22)
```

Comment: What is `geologs` ? If it's a collection, try : `db.collection('geologs').find...` instead.

Comment: what command did you try to run?
did you run db.<your collection>.find(...) instead of db.collection('<your collection>')).find(...) ?

Comment: Lauromine gave you the correct answer